# operand should contain 1 column(s) subquery MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have problem when I make a subquery

```html
select r.Request_ID,
(
(select e.ReportsTo, (select e1.FirstName from Employees e1 where e1.NIK = e.ReportsTo) as FirstName, 
(select e1.NIK from Employees e1 where e1.NIK=e.NIK) as Attention, 
(select e1.FirstName from Employees e1 where e1.NIK=e.NIK) as AttentionName 
from Employees e where e.ReportsTo ='CS-NIK-2016-0150' and e.NIK='CS-NIK-2016-0160')
)
from Request r where r.Request_ID='CS-REQ-BDG-201604-10099'
```

> operand should contain 1 column(s), Why?

Answer (score 0):

Use join instead of subquery. Also your subquery may be returns more than 1 row,So it shows the error.
To avoid the error use limit with each of the select which is not a best solution,as in this case it will return only the 1st row.

```
select r.Request_ID,
(
(select e.ReportsTo, (select e1.FirstName from Employees e1 where e1.NIK = e.ReportsTo limit 1) as FirstName, 
 e.NIK as Attention, FirstName as AttentionName 
from Employees e where e.ReportsTo ='CS-NIK-2016-0150' and e.NIK='CS-NIK-2016-0160')
)
from Request r where r.Request_ID='CS-REQ-BDG-201604-10099'
```